# C# Unity.Webapi Dependency Injections with EF 6 “An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker”

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, web-applications, entity-framework-6, webapi

So I am using Unity.Webapi for my DI
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/

I am randonly getting this error on saving "entity cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

I think the problem is how i have my Di Configured to inject the my DB Context

Here is my
Global.asax => Application Start

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
      FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
      UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();// this is the IOC DI for ENTITY FRAMEWORK SERVICES
      GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Unity.Config

```
public static class UnityConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
      UnityContainer container = new Unity.UnityContainer();
      container.EnableDiagnostic();
      var context = new EveModel();
      container.RegisterType<IRiskTypeRepo, RiskTypeRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRiskMatrixRepo, RiskMatrixRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRiskClosedReasonRepo, RiskClosedReasonRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRiskIssueManagementStrategyTypeRepo, RiskIssueManagementStrategyTypeRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<RiskMitigationStatusRepo.IRiskMitigationStatusRepo, RiskMitigationStatusRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRapidUserRepository, RapidUserRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRelMeasureRiskMitigationRepo, RelMeasureRiskMitigationRepo>();
      container.RegisterType<IRiskMitigationRepo, RiskMitigationRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRiskMitigationService, RiskMitigationService>();
      container.RegisterType<IMeasureRepo, MeasureRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IMeasureService, MeasureService>();
      container.RegisterType<InitiativeRepo, InitiativeRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IInitiativeService, InitiativeService>();
      container.RegisterType<IRiskMitigationService, RiskMitigationService>();
      container.RegisterType<IRiskRepository, RiskRepo>(new InjectionConstructor(context));
      container.RegisterType<IRiskService, RiskService>();    
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
  }
```

Rm Repo

```
using AuditWeb.Data.CodeFirst;
using AuditWeb.Data.Repos.Concrete;
using AuditWeb.Data.Repos.Contracts;
using AuditWeb.Data.Repos.LookUpRepositories;
using AuditWeb.Service.JsonModels;
using AuditWeb.Service.Services.Contracts;
using AuditWeb.Service.Services.Contracts.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AuditWeb.Service.Services.Concrete
{
    public class RiskMitigationService : IRiskMitigationService
    {
        private readonly IRiskMitigationRepo riskMitigationRepo;
        private readonly IMeasureService measureService;
        private readonly IUserRepository UserRepo;
        private readonly IRelMeasureRiskMitigationRepo relMeasureRmRepo;
        private readonly IRiskRepository riskRepo;
        private readonly DateTime currentTime;
        private readonly RiskMitigationStatusRepo.IRiskMitigationStatusRepo luRiskMigitgationStatus;
        private readonly IRiskIssueManagementStrategyTypeRepo luRiskManagementStrategyType;
        private User currentUser;
        public int currentUserId { get; set; } = 0;
        public RiskMitigationService(IRiskMitigationRepo _riskMitigationRepo
 
            , IRiskRepository _riskRep
            , IMeasureService _measureService
            , IUserRepository _UserRepo
            , RelMeasureRiskMitigationRepo _rmrmRepo
            , RiskMitigationStatusRepo.IRiskMitigationStatusRepo _luRiskMigitgationStatus
             , IRiskIssueManagementStrategyTypeRepo _luRiskManagementStrategyType
            )
        {
            riskMitigationRepo = _riskMitigationRepo;
            riskRepo = _riskRep;
            measureService = _measureService;
            currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            UserRepo = _UserRepo;
            relMeasureRmRepo = _rmrmRepo;
            luRiskMigitgationStatus = _luRiskMigitgationStatus;
            luRiskManagementStrategyType = _luRiskManagementStrategyType;
        }
        private RelMeasureRiskMitigation CreateNewMeasure() {

        return   new RelMeasureRiskMitigation()
            {
                //MeasureId = MeasureId, 
                //RiskMitigationId = obj.Id > 0 ? obj.Id : rm.Id,
                CreatedBy = this.currentUserId,
                LastModifiedBy = this.currentUserId,
                UpdatedTimestamp = currentTime,
                CreatedTimestamp = currentTime,
                CreatedByUser = currentUser,
                LastModifiedByUser = currentUser,
                ActiveFlag = true,
                DisplayFlag = false,
                Version = 1
            };
        }
        public RiskMitigation SaveUpdate(RiskMitigationJsonModel obj)
        {
            currentUser = UserRepo.GetById(this.currentUserId);
            RiskMitigation rm;
            if (obj.Id > 0)
            {
                rm.RiskId = obj.RiskId;
                rm.Owner = obj.OwnerId;
                rm.RiskMitigationStatusId = obj.MitigationStatusId;
                rm = UpdateStatus(rm, rm.ActiveFlag);
            }
            else
            {
                rm = ToBo(obj);
                 
            } 
            var rm1 = riskMitigationRepo.Save(rm);
            int totalCnt = relMeasureRmRepo.Count(s =>
              s.MeasureId == 102 && s.RiskMitigationId == obj.Id);
            int recCtn = 0;
            bool exists = false;    
            RelMeasureRiskMitigation newRel;
            foreach (int MeasureId in obj.RelMeasureMitigationIds)
            {
                if (rm.RelMeasureRiskMitigation.Any(s => s.MeasureId == MeasureId && s.RiskMitigationId == rm.Id))
                {
                    recCtn = rm.RelMeasureRiskMitigation.Count(s => s.MeasureId == MeasureId);
                    newRel = rm.RelMeasureRiskMitigation
                        .OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
                        .Where(s => s.MeasureId == MeasureId).Take(1).Single();
                    if (!newRel.ActiveFlag)
                    {
                        newRel.ActiveFlag = true;
                        newRel.LastModifiedBy = this.currentUserId;
                        newRel.UpdatedTimestamp = currentTime;
                        newRel.Version++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    newRel = CreateNewMeasure();
                    newRel.MeasureId = MeasureId;
                    newRel.Id = obj.Id > 0 ? obj.Id : rm.Id;
                    newRel.RiskMitigation = rm;
                    newRel.Measure = measureService.GetById(MeasureId);
                }
                try {   relMeasureRmRepo.Save(newRel);}
                catch (SqlException sqlex)              {}

                catch (Exception ex)    {}
            }
            return rm1;
        }
        private RiskMitigation ToBo(RiskMitigationJsonModel obj)
        {

            var owner = UserRepo.GetById(obj.OwnerId);
            try
            {
                var stratType = luRiskManagementStrategyType.GetById(obj.RiskIssueManagementStrategyTypeId);
                var status = luRiskMigitgationStatus.GetById(obj.MitigationStatusId);
                Risk risk = riskRepo.GetById(obj.RiskId);

                User approvedByAamdUser = null;
                User approvedByPmoUserId = null;
                if (obj.ApprovedByAamdUserId != null) {
                    approvedByAamdUser = UserRepo.GetById((int)obj.ApprovedByAamdUserId);
                }
                if (obj.ApprovedByPmoUserId != null)
                {
                    approvedByPmoUserId = UserRepo.GetById((int)obj.ApprovedByPmoUserId);
                }
                return new RiskMitigation()
                {
                    TrackingNumber =  obj.Id == 0   ? riskMitigationRepo.GenerateTrackingNumber(risk.OrganizationId, "RM") : "",
                    CreatedByUser = currentUser,
                    LastModifiedByUser = currentUser,
                    Id = 0,
                    UpdatedTimestamp = currentTime,
                    CreatedTimestamp = currentTime,
                    ActiveFlag = true,
                    CreatedBy = currentUserId,
                    LastModifiedBy = currentUserId,
                    Version = 1,
                    RiskManagementStrategyTypeId = obj.RiskIssueManagementStrategyTypeId,
                    RiskMitigationStatusId = obj.MitigationStatusId,
                    Actions = obj.Actions ?? "",
                    AnticipatedStartDate = obj.AnticipatedStartDate,
                    ApprovedByPmoUserId = obj.ApprovedByPmoUserId,
                    ApprovedByPmoUser = approvedByPmoUserId,
                    ApprovedByAamdFlag = obj.ApprovedByAamdFlag ?? false,
                    ApprovedByAamdTimestamp = obj.ApprovedByAamdTimestamp,
                    ApprovedByAamdUser = approvedByAamdUser,
                    ApprovedByPmoFlag = obj.ApprovedByPmoFlag ?? false,
                    ApprovedByAamdUserId = obj.ApprovedByAamdUserId,
                    ApprovedByPmoTimestamp = obj.ApprovedByPmoTimestamp,
                    ImpactStatement = obj.ImpactStatement ?? "",
                    Notes = obj.Notes ?? "",
                    Strategy = obj.Strategy ?? "",
                    RiskId = obj.RiskId,
                    Risk = risk,
                    Owner = obj.OwnerId,
                    OwnerUser = owner,
                    LuRiskMitigationStatus = status,
                    LuRiskManagementStrategyType = stratType
                };
            }
            catch (Exception exeption)
            {
                throw exeption;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message means that you can't have two version trackers working on the same entity.  Probably, you're reading an entity with one DataContext, and trying to write the same entity using a different DataContext.

Comment: I am gonna edit and add more, 1 repo

Comment: Or you could just find the place where you're using two different DataContext objects on the same entity.

Comment: It is blowing up on adding a new entity

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the specific part of the code that has the problem?

Comment: This line is where i get errors                 try {   relMeasureRmRepo.Save(newRel);} where it blows up in the Repo, all Repos are using the same repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223834/discussion-between-china-syndrome-and-robert-harvey).